# How to parse text from web content in java?

Tags: java, parsing, text, using

i would like to parse web content and get only text from the web content. I am getting web content as HTML/java script. Now i need only text from the content.
Can some one help me in doing this? I am using HTML parser to do this.

For example i need the text content in the below file which is in bold.

The `URLConnection` **class contains many methods that let you communicate with
the URL over the network. `URLConnection` is an HTTP-centric class; that
is,  many of its methods are useful only when you are working with HTTP
URLs. However, most URL protocols allow you to read from and write to
the connection. This section describes both functions.**

can some one suggest me or provide some sample code to do this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is the problem if you are already using a html parser?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Html parser. A safe choise will be [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanku. I tried using that. Can any one help me in parsing text using Html parser?

Answer (score 0):

An unorthodox method that i like to use is tools like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which is basically for unit testing, but they have advanced xpath parsing capabilities, provides automatic login, session handling kind of capabilities too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) for web download and [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) as html/xml parser.

I use them to extract infos from websites (Google search too).